# unofficial vine api not working

Tags: node.js, vine

I am trying to **connect to the vine API** to retrieve the list of uploaded videos of a given user.
I'm using a **node.js module** called [**Vineapple**](https://github.com/furf/vineapple).

The problem is **some of the api endpoints seems to not work anymore**

---

#### Here is a snippet that works

```
var vine = new vineapple({
    key: 'some-key',
    userId: '123456789',
    username: 'user',
}); 
vine.me(function(err, response){  // calls 'https://api.vineapp.com/users/me'
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(response);
});
```

This logs the whole vine user's settings:

```
{ followerCount: 300,
  includePromoted: 2,
  userId: '123456789',
  private: 0,
  likeCount: 30,
  ... etc }
```

---

#### And here is a snippet that does not work

```
var vine = new vineapple({
    key: 'some-key',
    userId: '123456789',
    username: 'user',
}); 
vine.user(connectionObject.userId.toString(), function(err, response){    // calls 'https://api.vineapp.com/timelines/users/{userId}'
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(response);
});
```

This never return anything.

Are all the vine api endpoints still available?

- If yes, what could be my problem?
- If no, is there another solution to retrieve vine videos?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are wondering.

As for today (april 2014), the vine unofficial api is still up. You can test it if here : https://api.vineapp.com/timelines/users/920890957405237248

I had a problem with the node.js vineapple module:

1/ You should always call vineapple functions with **promise syntax**:
https://github.com/furf/vineapple#promises

2/ Vine use big int as user ids, js cannot handle those so you should **send userId as js strings** and not numbers (I stored it as ints. The `.toString()` was useless here)

3/ There is a known bug in vineapple module, you should **comment line 121 of vineapple.js**: https://github.com/furf/vineapple/issues/2

As a conclusion, here is how my code look like:

```
var vine = new vineapple({
    key: key,
    userId: userId,     // Stored as String !
    username: username,
});
options= {page: '1', size: '20'};

vine.user(userId, options).then(function (response) {
    console.log('SUCCESS', response);
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.log('ERROR', error);
});
```

Hope it helps